# How to send JMS message with header & payload from .NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, apache, activemq-classic

I have a requirement where i need to send some messages onto the ACTIVEMQ from .NET side. I was sending something like this:

```
string destination="queue.name";
Hashtable message = new Hashtable();
message.Add("id", id);
message.Add("companyid", 12435);
message.Add("message", "Hello World");
Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(URI);
Spring.Messaging.Nms.Core.NmsTemplate template = new Spring.Messaging.Nms.Core.NmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
template.ConvertAndSend(destination, message);
```

This is what we were doing. But now listener is expecting "id" & "companyid" to be on header and "message" on payload.

How can i send this from .NET to ActiveMQ? Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
Nimi

Answer (score 0):

Not to familliar with the Spring.NET stuff but from the looks of it this should be sending a IMapMessage type message to ActiveMQ.   If you want the various bits to be in the Message headers than I think you need to use one of the methods that allows you to post process the message and move the values you want into the headers, or use a different API so you can create a different message type.